# Next/router cannot handle notFound in getServerSideProps

Tags: next.js, next-router

I have a link: `appBaseUrl/edit/:userId`
I want it to be transited by next/router like following:

```
router.push(`appBaseUrl/edit/${userId}`)
```

and in the getServerSideProps function is like following:

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async ({props}) => {
    const parsedProps = parseProps(props);
    const fetchedValues = await fetchFunction(params).data;
    // ... another 10 fetch queries
    if (!isValueValid(fetchedValues)) {return {notFound: true}}
    return {
        props: {
            ...parsedProps,
            fetchedValues,
            // ... other fetchedValues
        }
    }
}
```

No condition in the component function btw.

now the issue is,
if i visit the page directly by url with invalid userId, or by `window.location.replace`, the 404 show up as expected,
but when using next.router transition, it result in runtime error because react try to render page with undefined props).
Adding customized 404 page would not help.
I have not found working solutions so far.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you show us the `getServerSideProps` function?

Comment: Can you check if `getServerSideProps` is called when doing router.push? Your code should work as it is I believe

Comment: Just to sumarize your question, the `notFound:true` part is not working when you are doing router.push but is working when you change URL using other methods right

Comment: @TusharShahi Correct

Comment: Can you check if getServerSideProps is called when doing router.push? Your code should work as it is I believe - did you try this?

Answer (score 0):

Open issue of Next.
See this issue: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/38239